# Using Yocto with meta-balena causes a parse error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

I am new to using Yocto and bitbake.

I've inherited a project which was using an older version of Yocto - 1.8 Fido, and I need to update this to the latest possible version. I'm trying to update everything to 2.6 Thud.

The project was using meta-resin as one of the layers which is deprecated. It is now meta-balena whcih is one of the things i'm trying to change in the project.

I've faced multiple errors so far with the builds as expected, but the following is a new one which I don't know how to solve. Any help would be appreciated :

```
ERROR: ParseError at /home/paul/poky-thud/build-bbgw/../meta-balena/meta-balena-common/recipes-support/bindmount/bindmount_0.0.1.bb:3: Could not inherit file classes/cargo.bbclass
```

Comment: The build system can't find cargo.bbclass, it seems that such class doesn't exist anymore or it is part of other layer not included in your current project.

Comment: @danlor I see that cargo.bbclass is part of meta-rust : meta-rust/cargo.bbclass. Would this mean I should clone this layer also do you think? Thanks

Comment: That's right. You should add meta-rust to your project.